# Table not creating for django-background-tasks

Tags: django, background-task

I am new to django and i am trying to use background-tasks for sending mail notifications. But I am getting error as

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: background_task`

I have added `background_task` inside INSTALLED_APPS and gone through other related questions asked and so tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations background_task
```

But I am still getting same error.
I am using

```
Django==3.0.7
django-background-tasks==1.2.5
django-compat==1.0.15
```

Will appreciate any help

Comment: Did you forget to do `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I have tried manage.py migrate also, same error it is giving

Answer (score 3):

I was getting error with migrate and makemigrations, as I was first decorating the function or trying to use table,without it being even added and then using migrate.We should first migrate the tables and after that only we go on with using tables.                                                                                   A lesson learned.

Comment: Thanks, I had been stuck on this for an hour

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't follow the [docs](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) properly.

You don't need to make new migrations with background tasks.You just need to *migrate* after adding the `background_task` into the INSTALLED_APPS .

Just do:
`python manage.py migrate` and then run the tasks with `python manage.py process_tasks`.Be sure the django server is up and running before running the background tasks

Comment: HI Arjun , I  have first tried migrating but didn't got any success , so searched the other related answers and there they answered to use makemigrations. But anyway i am still getting the same error.