# Operational Error: no such table: background_task - clean way to deploy?

Tags: django, django-migrations, background-task

I have an issue with `background_tasks` and deploying. When running `makemigrations` I get:

```
no such table: background_task
```

here are my `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'appname.apps.AppnameConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'background_task',
]
```

I also tried `python manage.py makemigrations background_task` before `python manage.py makemigrations` but this also failed.

My workaround for now is to rename the `tasks.py` to `tasks` and to comment the part in the `urls.py` where I call the tasks from the `tasks.py` and deleting `background_task` from `settings.py`. Then I do all the migrating and then undo my renaming/commenting/deleting.
This works, but there must be a better way?
I already tried the tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120312/table-not-creating-for-django-background-tasks) (but my workaround is based a little bit on OPs own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63121439/4225972)) and [here](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-background-task/issues/14).

Comment: Have you tried migrating before making new migrations?

Comment: when you add an app it already included a migration file for the app tables, you only need to run migrate like from the document https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: when running migrate, I face the same error: `no such table`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command.

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Else:

You can delete your migrations (will delete your database) folder and then try recreating them again.

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Comment: This is exactly what happens when deploying - I have an empty database. I run `makemigrations` and immediately run into this error - I do not even get to do `migrate`. Only when I comment out every `background_task` related call.

Comment: Where are you deploying.

Comment: While looing for errors I just tried on my windows machine to delete the `migrations` folder and the `sqlite.db` file and ended up with the same error. Deploying and on my windows machine both works when using the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps [of documentation](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in order. If you have already the imports and usages of the background_task in your views, you need to comment them all, perform the `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, then uncomment them again.